# Bug in the C++ standard library in std::poisson_distribution?

Tags: c++, c++11, libstdc++, std

I think I have encountered an incorrect behaviour of std::poisson_distribution from C++ standard library.

### Questions:

1. Could you confirm it is indeed a bug and not my error?
2. What exactly is wrong in the standard library code of poisson_distribution function, assuming that it is indeed a bug?

### Details:

The following C++ code (file poisson_test.cc) is used to generate Poisson-distributed numbers:

```
#include <array>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main() {
  // The problem turned out to be independent on the engine
  std::mt19937_64 engine;

  // Set fixed seed for easy reproducibility
  // The problem turned out to be independent on seed
  engine.seed(1);
  std::poisson_distribution<int> distribution(157.17);

  for (int i = 0; i < 1E8; i++) {
    const int number = distribution(engine);
    std::cout << number << std::endl;
  }
}
```

I compile this code as follows:

```
clang++ -o poisson_test -std=c++11 poisson_test.cc
./poisson_test > mypoisson.txt
```

The following python script was used to analyze the sequence of random numbers from file mypoisson.txt:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def expectation(x, m):
    " Poisson pdf " 
    # Use Ramanujan formula to get ln n!
    lnx = x * np.log(x) - x + 1./6. * np.log(x * (1 + 4*x*(1+2*x))) + 1./2. * np.log(np.pi)
    return np.exp(x*np.log(m) - m - lnx)

data = np.loadtxt('mypoisson.txt', dtype = 'int')

unique, counts = np.unique(data, return_counts = True)
hist = counts.astype(float) / counts.sum()
stat_err = np.sqrt(counts) / counts.sum()
plt.errorbar(unique, hist, yerr = stat_err, fmt = '.', \
             label = 'Poisson generated \n by std::poisson_distribution')
plt.plot(unique, expectation(unique, expected_mean), \
         label = 'expected probability \n density function')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# Determine bins with statistical significance of deviation larger than 3 sigma
deviation_in_sigma = (hist - expectation(unique, expected_mean)) / stat_err
d = dict((k, v) for k, v in zip(unique, deviation_in_sigma) if np.abs(v) > 3.0)
print d
```

The script produces the following plot:

You can see the problem by bare eye. The deviation at n = 158 is statistically significant, it is in fact a 22σ deviation!

[image: You can see the problem by bare eye. The deviation at n = 158 is statistically significant, it is in fact a 22σ deviation!]

Close-up of the previous plot.

[image: Close-up of the previous plot.]

Comment: Which standard library is it? AFAIK, Clang tends to use libstdc++ on Linux and libc++ on Mac.

Comment: @chris I am on Ubuntu, I have checked that it is libstdc++. Printing out ____GLIBCXX____ gives 20160609. Concerning clang version, "clang -v" gives "clang version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4 (tags/RELEASE_380/final)" Can you reproduce the bug on Mac?

Comment: I don't have a Mac handy, I was simply verifying which implementation was actually being used because the two are wildly different.

Comment: I've compiled and run using Visual C++ 2017 (32 bit build) and I don't get the outlier.  (Value for 158 is around 0.03166, slightly lower than the value for 157 of 0.03182)

Comment: Please [report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/) that bug and give its URL in your question

Comment: Just a comment on the maths, the Poisson distribution is not continuous but discrete, and thus does not have a [probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function). You can calculate the [probability mass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function), though. I realize that your line plot helps to guide the eye, but the Poisson distribution does have non-integer variates, so plotting a continuous line is a bit misleading.

Comment: Looking at the source: `// NB: This case not in the book, nor in the Errata, but should be ok...` - I don't know a thing about the problem at hand (besides some very basic uni stuff about accept/reject algorithm), but it's the kind of statement that makes me nervous... :o)

Comment: @MatteoItalia Haha, I found the same piece of code, and was slightly worried as well.

Comment: @ChristophTerasa You are certainly right about probability density/mass function. I was taught statistics in Russian, so no wonder I have misused the term here. However note, that there is also a continuous counterpart of Poisson distribution (see e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.5990 and its reference to the book of Knuth), which can be used and is sometimes used to generate the discrete Poisson distribution.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

My system is set up as follows (Debian testing):

```
libstdc++-7-dev:
  Installed: 7.2.0-16

libc++-dev:
  Installed: 3.5-2

clang:
  Installed: 1:3.8-37

g++:
  Installed: 4:7.2.0-1d1
```

I can confirm the bug when using `libstdc++`:

```
g++ -o pois_gcc -std=c++11 pois.cpp
clang++ -o pois_clang -std=c++11 -stdlib=libstdc++ pois.cpp
clang++ -o pois_clang_libc -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ pois.cpp
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Did you [report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/) that bug? You probably should! Then give its URL in your question!

Comment: Credit does not go to me. I'd wait for @DmytroOliinychenko to report this, if he wants. Though if he decides not to I can do this as well.

Comment: Reported to GCC bugtracker.

Comment: @ChristophTerasa please link to the bug report

Comment: GCC bugtracker link: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=83237

Comment: @ChristophTerasa Thank you! This answer is very helpful, since now I know I can simply compile with "-stdlib=libc++" to get the correct distribution. I am tempted to accept this as the final correct answer, but as a scientist I wonder what's wrong with the libstdc++ implementation. That comment in the source code (// NB: This case not in the book, nor in the Errata, but should be ok...) is certainly suspicious, but I wasn't able to prove it is responsible for the bug.